# finding 4 elements that sum a given value (using hash table)

Tags: c++

I made a Hash table the size of 1000 from a 20 elements array (that i fill with random numbers from 10000 to 49999).

I want to create a function that gets a number and checks if there are 4 numbers in the hash table that sum to this number. What is the best method to do this so that the run time does not exceed O(n^2)?
I dont want to use the stl libary

I am using this double hash method:

```
hash1 = 3 middle digits in the number (for example 45897 -> 589)
hash2 = (key%1000)+1
```

Comment: Are you basically looking for a solution to the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)?

Comment: @MichaelMahn I'm looking for tips on how I can implement a function that is based on these principles but uses a Hash table

Comment: do you have a naive implementation of this to begin with? i.e. one that takes whatever time necessary to find the solution?

Comment: @AvinKavish  no :( because of it i want some tips what to try .. i already made hash table class

Comment: @Eden having a hash table does not differentiate it from being a sum of subset problem.

Comment: Yeah exactly, if you do come up with a way to use a hash table to decrease the time complexity of the problem that would be a new scientific discovery. But the math simply doesn't add up. Hashes help perform lookups, inserts and deletes in O(1) time but they don't solve mathematical problems.